# How to set an config parameter from console argument?

Tags: symfony

I'm a newbie in Symfony.

I trying to change Monolog output formatter by console argument 'format=json'.

In short, I want to run any console command with the way:

```
app/console my_command --format=json # xml / txt / my own
```

...and get output of LoggerInterface in requested format.

For example, I set the default formatter in configuration:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
            formatter: json_formatter
services:
    json_formatter:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter
```

When I create the some MyEventListener::onConsoleCommand ([as described here](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/11/symfony2-add-a-global-option-to-console-commands-and-generate-pid-file/)), I cannot change the parameters bag because it is already compiled: "Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag."

*Up2*: My services config in this case looks like this:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.command_dispatch:
        class: My\Listener\MyEventListener
        autowire: true
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.command }
```

With another way, I can register console option inside initial file:

```
# app/console
$loader = require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';
# ...
$application->getDefinition()->addOption(
    new InputOption(
        'formatter',
        'f',
        InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
        'The logs output formatter',
        'json_formatter'
    )
);
```

But I can't find a way to change parameters bag in the Container. Because $application->getKernel()->getContainer() is still empty.

So, how to change Symfony2 parameters from console input?

Alternatively, maybe I can just use some environments parameters? But how I can get an environment variable in YAML configuration?

Thank you.

**UP3:**
I have achieved the goal with environments variables like this:

```
SYMFONY__LOG__FORMATTER=json_formatter app/console my_command
monolog:
    handlers:
        console:
            type: console
            #...
            formatter: '%log.formatter%'
```

Comment: It seems like `onConsoleCommand` is the most convenient way. Can you add some more of your code and config trying it?

Comment: I have no problems to catch variable from onConsoleCommand. The main problem with this variant is that I just can't call $container->setParameter('formatter', 'json_formatter') inside onConsoleCommand()

Because of that problem: "Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag."

Comment: I've updated the question and added services config for onConsoleCommand() variant.

Comment: You can't call `$container->setParameter('formatter', 'json_formatter')` but you actually can `$container->get('monolog.handler.console')->setFormatter(...)`

Comment: Thank you, @Ziumin!

Comment: So, now you'll write the answer or maybe I will show full working code example?

Comment: Let me try to make a complete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only point to modify command arguments for every registered command of your application is handling `CommandEvents::COMMAND` that is triggered **before** any command has been executed. So you can modify its arguments and read them as described [here](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/11/symfony2-add-a-global-option-to-console-commands-and-generate-pid-file/). Also, at this point you have your container compiled and it is not possible to modify service's definitions at this point. But you can get any service.

So i think you can end up with following handler:

```
class LogFormatterEventListener
{
    private $container;
    private $consoleHandler;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, HandlerInterface $consoleHandler)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->consoleHandler = $consoleHandler;
    }

    public function onConsoleCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event)
    {
        $inputDefinition = $event->getCommand()->getApplication()->getDefinition();

        $inputDefinition->addOption(
            new InputOption('logformat', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Format of your logs', null)
        );

        // merge the application's input definition
        $event->getCommand()->mergeApplicationDefinition();

        $input = new ArgvInput();

        // we use the input definition of the command
        $input->bind($event->getCommand()->getDefinition());

        $formatter = $input->getOption('logformat');
        if ($formatter /** && $this->container->has($formatter) **/) {
            $this->consoleHandler->setFormatter(
                $this->container->get($formatter);
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I should say about this that mergeApplicationDefinition isn't work.
So, instead you can run $event->getCommand()->getDefinition()->addOption($option);
This will force option directly to current command.

And, the second, it's better to inject ConsoleHandler $handler to constructor after ContainerInterface.

Comment: Thank you. I've assumed that article's code is correct. Also I agree with you that we should avoid injecting Container anywhere, but it'll become a bit tricky to do it here (we'll then have to inject an array of all available formatters also). Btw, that is why I commented second check `container->has($formatter)`.

Comment: Yes, about formatter all is OK, but ConsuleHandler can be injected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative solution (compatible with common):

**Configuration:**

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
            formatter: "%log.formatter%"
services:
    json_formatter:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter
```

**Command execution:**

```
# colored plain text
app/console my_command

# json
SYMFONY__LOG__FORMATTER=json_formatter app/console my_command
```